# Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean in spring 3

Tags: spring, runtime-error, modelattribute, spring-form

Hi I am facing an issue and looked all over internet but still not able to find out the root cause. I am posting my code snippet please help me out as I am new to spring 3. I am using **modelAttribute** in form and what I want that in controller all the values from request should be backed in the object so that I can perform validation and other business logic.
I know there is mistake only in my controller.

1) index.jsp

```
<form:form action="login" method="POST" modelAttribute="login">
        <table>
            <tr><td>User Id:</td><td><form:input path="userId"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Password:</td><td><form:password path="userPassword"/></td></tr>
            <tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Login"/></td></tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
```

2) Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value="/login/", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(@ModelAttribute("login") @Valid Login login,BindingResult result)
    {

        System.out.println("We have entered into controller class");
        if(result.hasErrors())
        {
            System.out.println("Errors:"+result.getFieldError("userReject"));
                return "redirect:/login";
                }
                else
                {
        return "home";}
    }
}
```

3) JBoss Log

```
04:35:29,067 ERROR [org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.form.InputTag] (http--0.0.0.0-8090-1) Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'login' available as request attribute: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Neither BindingResult nor plain target object for bean name 'login' available as request attribute
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.BindStatus.<init>(BindStatus.java:141) [spring-webmvc-3.0.5.Release.jar:3.0.5.RELEASE]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not in the method you posted, which handles the login form *submission*. It's in the method used to *display* the form. The form needs to populate its fields from a bean named "login", and you didn't place any bean named "login" in the model, i.e. in a request attribute.

Side note: a login form should never use GET. It should use POST. You really don't want the password to appear in the browser address bar. And you don't want it to appear in the browser history, the server and proxy logs, etc.

Comment: Thanx @JB Nizet for your quick response. Since I am new I am not able to sort it out. Its a simple login page on which i will enter userid and userpassword and then in controller I will check it with DB and then validates the user. Could you please help me out with little code snippet as what changes I should do??? And thanx for the advice, It was my mistake. I have changed t back to POST

Comment: As I said, the error is in the method that you didn't show, and which is invoked in order to display the login form. Post this method. If you display the JSP directly, without going through a controller method, then fix that. Every request hould go through a controller. That's what MVC is all about.

Comment: but sir this is my index page. I mean when I start my app this should come first and ask user for credential, in this approach what to modify and what to fix. If you want i can provide git code if you want to take a look

Comment: No, I won't take a look. No JSP should be invoked directly. Everything should go through a controller.

Comment: thanx sir for your precious advice, I have changed my approach now, instead of calling directly the jsp I am going through controller now. Also i got the root cause of the problem that the form is trying to populate the field value from "login" model which is not instantiate thats y I was getting error. But sir I was thinking is there any other way in which I am calling only the jsp and I can set the model value null or blank before calling the jsp page?